# Return part of array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to find the fastest way to return a part of an array in C#
My current way is as follows:

```
// .. set int moveCount ..
// .. set int[] childArray ..
int[] realArray = new int[moveCount];
Array.Copy(childArray, realArray, moveCount);
return realArray;
```

This is the way I see it everywhere on the net, but
I wonder if the array will be copied twice now. Once because I do it, and once because of returning.

- Is this a right assumption?.
- Is there a better way? I know about Buffer.BlockCopy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, when you return you'll be returning a *reference* to the array you've just created. The reference will be copied, but that's dirt cheap.

All arrays are reference types, even if the *element* type of the array is a value type (so `int[]` is a reference type even though `int` is a value type).

Now you could still consider returning `ArraySegment<int>` instead of `int[]` - that way you wouldn't end up copying *any* values within the array. On the other hand, if the original array is changed, those changes will affect what the caller sees (and likewise the caller can change the array contents).

Comment: Ah I wrongly assumed arrays were passed by value. I don't always get it with C#. Thanks

Comment: @AartStuurman, go through this article [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by the great man

Comment: @AartStuurman: Array *references* are passed by value by default, just like all other reference types. It's not that arrays are passed by references - it's that the references are passed by value. There's a big difference.

Comment: Yes sorry, that is what I meant to type.

Answer (score 3):

No, your assumption is wrong, your return statement returns a reference to the created array. So no, you are not creating two copies of the array returned. For the part regarding the block copy, I think that your Array.Copy is the best tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

If sounds like you want to use LINQ `Take`:

```
return realArray.Take(numberOfItems);
```

*Note: This works for taking the first to N elements in the array*

Comment: I will gives this a try. It does what I need, but I don't know if it's faster.

Comment: @AartStuurman: Whether it's faster or not, depends on what you are doing with the result. Note that you return an `IEnumerable<int>` instead of an `int[]`, so you can't access it like an array, only loop through it.